# View does not update when changing RealmObject passed as binding

Tags: swift, swiftui, realm

I have a view, where I have an array of RealmObjects. When I pass them into another `View` via `@Binding` and try to edit them there, the `View` does not get updated.

This is a simplified example. When the name changes, it dumps the correct name into the console, but the `View` does not update. Tried to force a reload by changing the `.id()` of the `View`, but this doesn't help either.

```swift
class Person: Object, ObjectIdentifiable {
  @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId
  @Persisted var name: String = ""
}

struct ParentView: View {
  @State private var persons: [Person] = []

  var body: some View {
    ChildView(persons: $persons)
  }
}

struct ChildView: View {
  @Binding var persons: [Person]

  var body: some View {
    ForEach(person) { person in
      Text(person.name)
        .onTapGesture {
          person.name = "New Name"
          dump(person)
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue is mixing two different technologies by assigning Realm objects to a Swift array - generally speaking, that may not be the best idea.

Realm objects are lazily-loaded and massive datasets take almost no memory. However, as soon as those objects are cast to Swift functions and constructs they are *all* loaded into memory and can overwhelm the device.

Best practice is to keep Realm objects within Realm stuctures e.g. Collections like Results and Lists.

To address the question:

Realm provides an object @ObservedResults which is a property wrapper that invalides a view when observed objects change. e.g. If the app has @ObservedResults of a group of People objects, if one of those changes, the associated view will also update. From the docs

> You can use this property wrapper to create a view that automatically
> updates itself when the observed object changes.

So change this

```
struct ChildView: View {
  @Binding var persons: [Person]
```

to this

```
struct ChildView: View {
  @ObservedResults(Person.self) var persons
```

I think the rest of the code is good to go as is.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I fully unterstand that it's not the best idea to mix the array and the List or Result of RealmItems. But think of it like the example that Realm gives you in the tutorial:

I'm creating a Person, and inside the sheet where the person get's created, I'm adding some Dogs, that I will then add to the Person at the end, but when I'm using ```@ObservedResults```, I'll get all possible Dog objects back. But I'll look into it.

Comment: @treboc Ah! That's easily corrected. Just add a filter to your @ObservedResults! For example `@ObservedResults(Person.self, filter: NSPredicate(format: "name == 'Jay'")) var persons` will filter your results for only people with the name of 'Jay'