# How to update list array in realm no error

Tags: swift, realm

In this piece of code i am trying to update object, but am having trouble updating array of lists causes unexpected results, specifically when applying editTask script it seems they add new object into Realm, but did not update the data. I am not sure what part of my code is wrong, help me to fix this editTask in Realm.

This is my realm model:

```
class DatabaseTask {
    
    static let shared = DatabaseTask()
    
     var realm = try! Realm()
    
    func createTask(title: String, date: String, startTime: String, endTime: String, users: [User], category: [Categories], status: [Status]) {
        try! realm.write {
            let task = Task()
            task.title = title
            task.date = date
            task.startTime = startTime
            task.endTime = endTime
            let listUser = List<User>()
            listUser.append(objectsIn: users)
            task.user = listUser
            let listCategory = List<Categories>()
            listCategory.append(objectsIn: category)
            task.category = listCategory
            let listStatus = List<Status>()
            listStatus.append(objectsIn: status)
            task.status = listStatus
            realm.add(task)
        }
    }
        
    func editTask(task: Task?, newTitle: String, newDate: String, newStartTime: String, newEndTime: String , newUser: [User], newCategory: [Categories]) {
        try! realm.write {
            task?.title = newTitle
            task?.date = newDate
            task?.startTime = newStartTime
            task?.endTime = newEndTime
            task?.user.removeAll()
            task?.user.append(objectsIn: newUser)
            task?.category.removeAll()
            task?.category.append(objectsIn: newCategory)
        }
    }
```

This is the screen to handle create and edit : I at the taskEdit variable to store data from the previous screen, now when I have the data from the screen I just created the realm, I take the data taskEdit to edit the data realm again

```
import UIKit

class TaskCalenderVC: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var myTable: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var btMore: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var createTask: UIButton!
    
    var arrUsers: [User] = []
    var arrCategori: [Categories] = []
    var arrStatus: [Status] = []
    var titleTask: String = ""
    var dateTask : String = ""
    var startTimes: String = ""
    var endTimes : String = ""
    
    var taskEdit: Task?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myTable.dataSource = self
        myTable.delegate = self
    }
    
    @IBAction func createTasks(_ sender: Any) {
        
        let saveTasks = DatabaseTask.shared.getTask()
        
        let titleOverlapping = saveTasks.contains(where: { $0.title == titleTask })
        let dateOverlapping = saveTasks.contains(where: { $0.date == dateTask })
        let startTimeOverlapping = saveTasks.contains(where: { $0.startTime == startTimes })
        let endTimeOverlapping = saveTasks.contains(where: { $0.endTime == endTimes })
        let usersOverlapping = saveTasks.contains(where: { $0.user.toArray().contains(where: { arrUsers.contains($0) }) })
        
        if titleOverlapping || dateOverlapping || startTimeOverlapping || endTimeOverlapping || usersOverlapping {
            
            showAlert(with: "Error", message: "Task values overlap or are empty.")
            
        } else {
            
            if let taskEdit = taskEdit {
                // Edit task
                DatabaseTask.shared.editTask(task: taskEdit, newTitle: titleTask, newDate: dateTask, newStartTime: startTimes, newEndTime: endTimes, newUser: arrUsers, newCategory: arrCategori)
                
            } else {
                // Create task
                DatabaseTask.shared.createTask(title: titleTask, date: dateTask, startTime: startTimes, endTime: endTimes, users: arrUsers, category: arrCategori, status: arrStatus)
            }
            self.dismiss(animated: true)
            self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
            
        }
    }
        func showAlert(with title: String, message: String) {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Part of the art of coding is *troubleshooting*. One way to troubleshoot is to add a breakpoint and step through the code line by line, inspecting the vars and code execution until you spot something unexpected. It's really important to do that step and then include which line is not correct in the question. There are some other issues with the code as well; for example in this `func editTask(task: Task?` the code states that Task is optional, meaning it could be nil. However, when you call that function, this ensures that task is never nil `if let taskEdit = taskEdit {`. So that's little odd.

Comment: The case if let taskEdit = taskEdit means that taskEdit already has data from the previous screen, it will check if there is data, then it will jump into the EditTask function below. otherwise, if not, it will create new data. I didn't catch any

Comment: Again, troubleshooting is important and asking a clear question will help lead to a correct answer. For example; the `TaskCalenderVC` class defines `arrUsers` which is an empty array. Then when the task is edited `DatabaseTask.shared.editTask(... users: arrUsers...` that *empty array* is passed and then assigned to the task user property `task?.user.append(objectsIn: newUser)`. So... troubleshooting per the above comment, will help catch mistakes like that.

Answer (score -1):

And the editTask function error in Realm model I found the solution to   fix it, why the removeAll() function it really doesn't work with List I think is like that. Here is an alternative for removeAll() function.

```
 func editTask(task: Task?, newTitle: String, newDate: String, newStartTime: String, newEndTime: String ,newUser: [User], newCategory:  [Categories]) {
    try! realm.write {
        if let list = task?.user {
            realm.delete(list)
        }
        if let list = task?.category {
            realm.delete(list)
        }
        task?.title = newTitle
        task?.date = newDate
        task?.startTime = newStartTime
        task?.endTime = newEndTime
        task?.user.append(objectsIn: newUser)
        task?.category.append(objectsIn: newCategory)
     }
 }
```

Also, when you want to convert list to an array of objects, add two extensions.Now the list is already an array of objects. Code is much easier now

```
 extension List where Element: Any {
 func toArray() -> [Element] {
    return Array(self)
  }
}

extension Results {
func toArray<T>(ofType: T.Type) -> [T] {
    var array = [T]()
    for i in 0 ..< count {
        if let result = self[i] as? T {
            array.append(result)
          }
       }
        return array
    }
 }
```

Comment: I am not sure how this addresses the question but you can greatly simplify things. Realm Lists can be directly cast to an array. `let myTaskArray = Array(taskList)` - however there are downsides to casting a List to an Array - see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74516183/view-does-not-update-when-changing-realmobject-passed-as-binding/74524100#74524100) Secondly, `RemoveAll` works with Realm list `taskList.removeAll` removes all of the tasks in the list.